# Umbraco: Property inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

My content structure is like this:

```
-Home
  -Page1
     -SubPage1
        -SubSubPage1
        -SubSubPage2
     -SubPage2
  -Page2
  -Page3
```

**Q:** How can I set a property only once in Page1 so that is inherited by all pages under it and visible only in those pages and not the parent (Page1). Currently I have a master template (Layout) that renders the main content containing a single template for most of pages that checks for HasProperty && HasValue

Comment: This is in no way Umbraco 7 specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sub-pages don't actually *need* the value to be *set* on them, but do need the value to be displayed on them when published (because the are descendants of the Page1), then you can do this in your template:

```
@if(Model.Content.Ancestors("Page1DocTypeAlias").Any()){
    @Model.Content.Ancestor("Page1DocTypeAlias").GetPropertyValue("propertyAlias")
}
```

This will check whether the current page is a descendant of Page1 (or specifically a page of type "Page1DocTypeAlias"). If it is then it will extract the property from Page1 and display it.